# Header Content-Type defined in axios not working

Tags: javascript, java, spring-security, axios, http-headers

I'm having a little trouble to integrate my login frontend logics (**Vue3** + **Axios**) to my Java API (with **Spring Security**).

I'm getting the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: (org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream); line: 1, column: 0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4344) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4189) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3242) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at br.com.preferencialsaude.app.JWTLoginFilter.attemptAuthentication(JWTLoginFilter.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
```

While debugging I've found out that no "Content-Type: application/json" header is present in my HttpServletRequest, but the problem is that **I'm actually setting it** in my **axios client**.

When I make the request from postman, it works fine, but when I try to make from my frontend app, I get the previous error.

I thought it could be the browser, but it ends up in the same freaking error in any browser. I've even tried to make the request with JS Fecth API, but the behavior remains the same.

The MimeHeaderFields when I make the request from browser:

```
host, connection, accept, access-control-request-method, access-control-request-headers,
origin,user-agent, sec-fetch-mode, sec-fetch-site, sec-fetch-dest, referer,
accept-encoding, accept-language
```

As you can see, there's no `Content-Type`, but it is present when I make request from postman.

Here is my client-side code:

```
async handleSubmit () {
    const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/ws/login',
      { username: this.login, password: this.senha }, { 
        headers: { 
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
      });

    console.log(response.data)
    localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
}
```

And here is my backend Java filter:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import br.com.preferencialsaude.app.model.AccountCredentials;
import br.com.preferencialsaude.app.service.TokenAuthenticationService;

public class JWTLoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    protected JWTLoginFilter(String url, AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(url));
        setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {

        //here is where I get the error, due to the lack of Content-Type header
        AccountCredentials credentials = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), AccountCredentials.class);

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken userAuthData =
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(credentials.getUsername(), credentials.getPassword(), Collections.emptyList());

        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(userAuthData);
    }
```

And this is the result I get in postman:

```
{"token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ0aGFseXMiLCJleHAiOjE2NDYzMzM2OTB9.5wYyYs6jwhIsxob99Ubx4b64jIIMjVKXf0bZ_ZS_zhkPtrK0KOgKxOgy0HgxlEdV_F5DTwOeDooqVRouEuAqEA"}
```

with **status** code **200**

Here is my WebSecurityConfig class:

```
package br.com.preferencialsaude.app;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import br.com.preferencialsaude.app.service.MyUserDetailsService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
    public WebSecurityConfig(MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }
    
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }
    
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/ws/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/ws/login", authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/gerenciador/home", true)
                .usernameParameter("usuario")
                .passwordParameter("senha")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/gerenciador/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/gerenciador/login").and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/error");
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(
           "/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/imagens/**",
            "/webfonts/**", "/jasper/**", "/contratos/**",
            "/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-resources/**", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**",
            "/procedimento/**", "/procedimento/**/**", "/credenciamento/empresa/**", "/credenciamento/pessoa/**",
            "/credenciamento/farmacia/**", "/buscaCep", "/plano/**", "/contrato/empresa/**",
            "/contrato/pessoa-fisica/**", "/rede-credenciada/**", "/ws/rede-credenciada/**", "/ws/endereco/**",
            "/ws/procedimentos/**", "/ws/recuperar-senha/**", "/api/cupons-venda/**", "/atendimento/**",
            "/termos", "/convenio/**", "/ws/agendamento/**", "/ws/consulta/**", "/ws/notificacoes/**", "/ws/avaliacao/**",
            "/ws/imagens/**", "/actuator/**", "/api/enderecos/**", "/api/cadastros-clientes/**", "/api/cidades/**",
            "/api/planos/**", "/api/especialidades-saude/consultas/**", "/api/rede-atendimento/**"
        );
    }
}
```

And here is my JWTLoginFilter:

```
package br.com.preferencialsaude.app;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import br.com.preferencialsaude.app.model.AccountCredentials;
import br.com.preferencialsaude.app.service.TokenAuthenticationService;

public class JWTLoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    protected JWTLoginFilter(String url, AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(url));
        setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {

        AccountCredentials credentials = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), AccountCredentials.class);

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken userAuthData =
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(credentials.getUsername(), credentials.getPassword(), Collections.emptyList());

        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(userAuthData);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                            FilterChain filterChain, Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
        TokenAuthenticationService.addAuthentication(response, auth.getName());
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                              AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        TokenAuthenticationService.failAuthentication(response);
    }
}
```

Have you ever faced a similar problem? I appreciate any help!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242318/discussion-on-question-by-thalys-menezes-header-content-type-defined-in-axios-no).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out how to resolve this by adding some CORS configuration in my WebSecurityConfig file.

The problem wasn't the Content-Type Header at all, but Spring Security that was blocking OPTIONS requests.

This is the piece of code I added to solve the issue

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean processCorsFilter() {     
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:8080", "http://localhost:8081",
                "https://site.preferencialsaude.com.br", "https://site-hmlg.preferencialsaude.com.br"));
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/ws/login", config);
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/api/**", config);


    final FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return bean;
}
```

Found this code in a comment inside this CORS configuration tutorial: https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework

If you want to accept requests from all origins, just replace the `setAllowedOrigins() with addAllowedOrigin("*")`, since the way I configured it, as in the code above, I cannot login from postman, or any other origins except the ones I defined.